# Unable to deploy Vue+Vite frontend to Heroku due to path troubles

Tags: heroku, deployment, vuejs3, vite

I apologize in advance if the question is not posed entirely correct. I will also be quick to provide extra information if it appears I have forgotten something, as this is my first post on SO.

Currently, I have:

- Deployed my FastAPI backend to Heroku
- Deployed my db to Atlas (MongoDB).

As I am developing a fullstack application, I am now trying to deploy the Vue + Vite frontend.
However, I am encountering an issue when i try to push the branch to Heroku (using Heroku CLI).

```
remote: [vite:load-fallback] Could not load /src/components/Navbar.vue (imported by src/App.vue): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/components/Navbar.vue'
remote: error during build:
remote: Error: Could not load /src/components/Navbar.vue (imported by src/App.vue): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/components/Navbar.vue'
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Both from the error message and from other peoples' issues here on stack overflow, it seems apparent that I must have misspelled the Navbar.vue path inside of App.vue. However, I cannot seem to see the mistake:

**App.Vue**

```
<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue';
  
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Navbar,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        links: ["https://github.com/karolisw/hyperFetch"],
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="app" >
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
      <transition name="scale-slide" mode="out-in">
        <component :is="Component"></component>
      </transition>
    </router-view>
    </div>
    <v-footer class="bg-blue-grey-darken-4">
      <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
        <v-btn
          v-for="link in links"
          :key="link"
          color="white"
          variant="text"
          class="mx-2"
          rounded="xl"
        >
          {{ link }}
        </v-btn>
        <v-col class="text-center mt-4" cols="12">
          {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} — <strong>my:name@my_uni</strong>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-footer>  
  </v-app>
</template>
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/src',
    },
  },
})
```

This is what I've written into the terminal

1. Downloaded heroku cli
2. Created an app in Heroku called *frontend*
3. Built my application
   `vite build`
4. Tried to push my application
   `git push heroku frontend:master`